# wordpress plugin visit counter not working properly

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a plugin for wordpress visitor counter and limit counts of visitor. I wrote this code, but counter variable increments 4 times or 5 times every time I refresh the page. Basically plugin is for free visits after free visits user should be logged in to visit website. Please check the code.

```php
<?php
    $count=0;

    function ip_get(){

        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
            //ip from share internet
            $new_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
            //ip pass from proxy
            $new_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }else{
            $new_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        global $wpdb;
        $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'wbs_user_ips';

        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
        if(empty($results)){
            $wpdb->insert($table_name,
                array(
                      'user_ip'=>$new_ip,      
                      'user_count'=>'1',      
                      'user_status'=>'0',    

                )
                );
        }

        if(!empty($results))     // Checking if $results have some values or not
        {  
            $count=0;
            foreach($results as $row){
                $ip= $row->user_ip;
                $count=$row->user_count;
            }

            if($ip==$new_ip){
                echo $count++;

                $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name 
                            SET user_count=".$count."
                            WHERE user_ip = %s",$ip));
            }   
        } 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your foreach loop.
And please make sure you use the correct [hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

```
<?php

$count=0;

function ip_get(){

    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        //ip from share internet
        $new_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        //ip pass from proxy
        $new_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $new_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'wbs_user_ips';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
    if(empty($results)){
        $wpdb->insert($table_name,
            array(
                  'user_ip'=>$new_ip,      
                  'user_count'=>'1',      
                  'user_status'=>'0',    

            )
            );
    }

    if(!empty($results))     // Checking if $results have some values or not
    {  
        $count=0;
        foreach($results as $row){
            $ip= $row->user_ip;
            $count=$row->user_count;

            if($ip==$new_ip){
                echo $count++;

                $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name 
                        SET user_count=".$count."
                        WHERE user_ip = %s",$ip));
            }   
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: i want to show the counts on front-end when a user visits the page can you tell me which hook should i use?

Comment: i think 'wp' hook works for counting. where do you want to show visits?

Comment: ON main website page .as a alert

Comment: you can use wp_head if aler is rendered by Javascript or you can use wp_footer and place html in the footer.

Comment: but still count variable increment 4 time like if my visit is 4 when i refresh the page it goes directly to 4 times and then 8 time so on

Comment: thnks i solved my problem problem is in the localhost . in local host chrome refresh the page twice when i press f5 button